# BeautifulSoup. NameError: name 'soup' is not defined

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Всем привет.

Пробую найти с помощью BeautifulSoup ссылки в хтмл-документе.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html.parser import HTMLParser
url = "www"
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)


links = soup.findAll('a',href = true)
print(links[5])
```

Ругается, NameError: name 'soup' is not defined

Почему? Если soup.findAll должно нормально куриться...

Спасибо

Comment: Ну у вас на самом деле нет никакой переменной soup, откуда она по-вашему должна взяться?

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html.parser import HTMLParser
url = "www"
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile, 'html.parser')

links = soup.findAll('a',href = true)
print(links[5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup('lxml', htmlfile)
```